# How to get an element from multidimensional ArrayList?

Tags: java

First of all I'm newbie in Java. I need to get each of element from array, so I can break the lines and add some static text. I have something like this:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> produkty;

produkty = GUI_main.getFacade().items();  

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> items()

for(ArrayList<String> a : Produkty_form.produkty){
   System.out.println(a);
   area.append(a + "\n");
}
```

This give me result:

```
 [1, data, category, 100.0, 10, Tue Jan 16 11:52:18 CET 2018, 90.0]
```

and I expected result like this:

```
1,
data,
category,
100.0,
...
```

What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Produkty_form what is that ? it is object ?

Comment: The first iteration gives you a list of strings back, you need a second iteration over the inner list to get each element. Check Erans answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested loops if you wish each element of the inner [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html)s to be printed on a separate line:

```
for(ArrayList<String> a : Produkty_form.produkty){
   for(String s : a){
       System.out.println(s + ',');
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. :)